# jQuery Drag Drop cancel when the dragged item is the last draggable object from the originate container

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple DropZone defined, each dropZone need to keep at least one draggable object.

When the user try to move the last item from a dropZone, I need to warn the user, that the last item cannot be moved and cancel the move action. I read that the ui.render was accessible on the receive event, although it's always empty.

I would need to access the original draggable parent (the dropZone it come from) and calculate the count of draggable children. When the count is now 0, I would cancel the move action so that the dragged block return to it's original position.

Something like:

```
function SortableReceiveDrag(event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.sender).find("div.dragableBlock").length <= 0) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');        
    }
}
```

And my binding is as following:

```
var templateContent = $("#templatectn");
contentDropZones = templateContent.find('div.ContentZone.dropZone');
contentDropZones.sortable({
    accept: 'div.dragableBlock',
    connectWith: 'div.ContentZone.dropZone',
    appendTo: "parent",
    axis: false,
    containment: 'document',
    cursor: 'move',
    cursorAt: false,
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    forceHelperSize: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    iframeFix: true,
    items: 'div.dragableBlock',
    greedy: true,
    grid: false,
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: 0.45,
    placeholder: 'ui-block-placeholder',
    revert: false,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 20,
    scrollSpeed: 20,
    scope: "default",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    zIndex: 2700,
    start: function (event, ui) { SortableStartDrag(event, ui); },
    stop: function (event, ui) { SortableStopDrag(event, ui); },
    receive: function (event, ui) { SortableReceiveDrag(event, ui); },
    change: SortableChange
});
contentDropZones.disableSelection();
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Thanks,
Francois

Comment: Got it, here's the working code:

    function SortableReceiveDrag(event, ui) {
        if (ui.sender) {
            if ($(ui.sender).children("div.dragableBlock").length <= 0) {
                $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
                alert("Sorry, a least one block need to exist per column.");
            }
        }
    
        $(ui.sender).sortable("refresh");
    }

For some reason I needed to use children, instead of find.

Cheers,
Francois

Comment: Please add this as an answer for others